# How to get only one value in Javascript array of objects using for of and for in statements?

Tags: javascript

Here is my array of objects, where I want to get specific value.

```
const customerData = [
  { customerName: "Jay", Purchased: "phone", Price: "€200" },
  { customerName: "Leo", Purchased: "car", Price: "€2000" },
  { customerName: "Luk", Purchased: "Xbox", Price: "€400" },
];
```

in this function I get all values together. But I want specific value in order to show smth like this in console  using for of and for in statements. `"Dear  Jay thank you for purchase of a phone for the price of €200 "`

````
function getValue(){
 for(let key of customerData){
for(let value in key){
  console.log(key[value]) //I get all values 
  //console.log(value)  // I get all keys
}
 }
}

getValue();```
````

Comment: that means for in and for of statements are powerless in this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need multiple for loop for this. You can do this using one [`forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) loop and [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) like:

```js
var customerData = [{ customerName: "Jay", Purchased: "phone", Price: "€200" },
  { customerName: "Leo", Purchased: "car", Price: "€2000" },
  { customerName: "Luk", Purchased: "Xbox", Price: "€400" },
];

function getValue() {
  customerData.forEach(x => {
    console.log(`Dear ${x.customerName} thank you for purchase of a ${x.Purchased} for the price of ${x.Price}`)
  })
}

getValue();
```

Comment: that means for in and for of statements are useless in this case?

Comment: For-in useless in this case, but you can still do it using a for-of loop. But forEach is better as you don't have to create a new variable using let in forEach for looping.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var customerData = [{ customerName: "Jay", Purchased: "phone", Price: "€200" },
  { customerName: "Leo", Purchased: "car", Price: "€2000" },
  { customerName: "Luk", Purchased: "Xbox", Price: "€400" },
]
    function getValue(){
         for(let key of customerData){
        for(let value in key){
          console.log(key[value]) //I get all values 
          break;
        //It Work
        }
         }
        }
    
        getValue();
```

Answer (score 1):

By passing the object position in the array as a parameter for the function you can get the single object keys

```
function getValue(data){
    for(let key of Object.values(data)){
        console.log(key)
    }
}

getValue(a[1]);
```

// Output
Leo car €2000

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the name of the customer you're looking for and the data you want about them. Then you can use `Array.filter()` and `Array.map()`

Then you can put the functions into a template literal to get your result.

```js
let customerData=[{customerName:"Jay",Purchased:"phone",Price:"€200"},{customerName:"Leo",Purchased:"car",Price:"€2000"},{customerName:"Luk",Purchased:"Xbox",Price:"€400"}]

function getValue(name, otherKey) {
  return customerData.filter(obj => obj.customerName === name).map(obj => obj[otherKey])[0]
}

console.log(getValue("Jay", "Purchased"))
console.log(getValue("Luk", "Price"))


let str = `Dear Jay thank you for purchase of a ${getValue("Jay", "Purchased")} for the price of ${getValue("Jay", "Price")}`

console.log(str)
```